# Why does minecraft crash when getting the Instance?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

My fabric minecraft client based utility mod crashed the game when it hits this line

`MinecraftClient minecraftClient = MinecraftClient.getInstance();` This is line 21 by the way

Here is the crash report link: https://mclo.gs/QVOqz5G

And here is the full code in case the getInstance part is not whats causing the error

```
package net.mariuchinas.dorts.commands;

import com.mojang.brigadier.builder.LiteralArgumentBuilder;
import meteordevelopment.meteorclient.commands.Command;
import net.minecraft.client.network.AbstractClientPlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.command.CommandSource;
import net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient;
import net.minecraft.client.network.ClientPlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.client.world.ClientWorld;
import java.util.List;

public class GetPlayersCommand extends Command {
    public GetPlayersCommand() {
        super("getplayers", "Sends a list of all the players on the server");
    }

    @Override
    public void build(LiteralArgumentBuilder<CommandSource> builder) {
        builder.executes(context -> {
            // Get the client instance and the current world
            MinecraftClient minecraftClient = MinecraftClient.getInstance();
            ClientWorld clientWorld = minecraftClient.world;

            // Check if the world and client player are available
            if (clientWorld != null && minecraftClient.player != null) {
                // Get the list of players
                List<AbstractClientPlayerEntity> players = clientWorld.getPlayers();

                // Iterate over the players and do something with their names
                for (AbstractClientPlayerEntity player : players) {
                    String playerName = player.getEntityName();
                    // Do something with the player name
                    System.out.println(playerName);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }


}
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.mariuchinas.dorts.commands.GetPlayersCommand.lambda$build$0(GetPlayersCommand.java:21)
    at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.execute(CommandDispatcher.java:263)
    at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.execute(CommandDispatcher.java:177)
    at com.mojang.brigadier.CommandDispatcher.execute(CommandDispatcher.java:142)
    at meteordevelopment.meteorclient.commands.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:75)
    at net.minecraft.class_634.handler$zmj000$meteor-client$onSendChatMessage(class_634.java:5826)
    at net.minecraft.class_634.method_45729(class_634.java)
    at net.minecraft.class_408.method_44056(class_408.java:250)
    at net.minecraft.class_408.method_25404(class_408.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_1454(class_309.java:394)
    at net.minecraft.class_437.method_25412(class_437.java:540)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_1466(class_309.java:390)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_22678(class_309.java:478)
    at net.minecraft.class_1255.execute(class_1255.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_22676(class_309.java:478)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallbackI.callback(GLFWKeyCallbackI.java:44)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents(GLFW.java:3403)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.pollEvents(RenderSystem.java:198)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.flipFrame(RenderSystem.java:209)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.class_408
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.class_437.method_25412(class_437.java:540)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_1466(class_309.java:390)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_22678(class_309.java:478)
    at net.minecraft.class_1255.execute(class_1255.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.class_309.method_22676(class_309.java:478)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallbackI.callback(GLFWKeyCallbackI.java:44)
    at org.lwjgl.system.JNI.invokeV(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents(GLFW.java:3403)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.pollEvents(RenderSystem.java:198)
    at com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem.flipFrame(RenderSystem.java:209)
    at net.minecraft.class_1041.method_15998(class_1041.java:310)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1523(class_310.java:1238)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1514(class_310.java:801)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:237)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:468)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    All players: 35 total; [class_746['MARIUCHINAS'/87477, l='ClientLevel', x=4.46, y=91.00, z=-3.78], class_745['alessandrobrodiz'/85566, l='ClientLevel', x=3.94, y=90.00, z=1.88], class_745['1Spider1'/86609, l='ClientLevel', x=-15.47, y=90.00, z=4.59], class_745['smith451'/76890, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=90.00, z=4.50], class_745['§r'/202, l='ClientLevel', x=7.50, y=90.00, z=1.50], class_745['Petermh'/66889, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=90.00, z=4.50], class_745['Lolman_PL'/87424, l='ClientLevel', x=-1.06, y=87.02, z=-5.30], class_745['CalypsoAlt3'/73697, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=90.00, z=4.50], class_745['Duk1'/87009, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=90.00, z=4.50], class_745['QuFox'/178, l='ClientLevel', x=3.66, y=111.50, z=17.97], class_745['§rBotervrij'/181, l='ClientLevel', x=3.63, y=111.50, z=24.00], class_745['§rJustThiemo'/184, l='ClientLevel', x=3.47, y=111.50, z=20.97], class_745['§rvoodootje0'/187, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=111.50, z=26.50], class_745['Andeh'/175, l='ClientLevel', x=-2.47, y=111.50, z=23.94], class_745['§rGunfire'/190, l='ClientLevel', x=-2.50, y=111.50, z=20.97], class_745['Rodagave115'/212, l='ClientLevel', x=-2.72, y=111.50, z=18.00], class_745['poseidonzubrik'/85794, l='ClientLevel', x=-4.69, y=90.94, z=-0.20], class_745['§r'/193, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=93.06, z=36.47], class_745['Nirahz'/205, l='ClientLevel', x=-27.75, y=90.00, z=1.16], class_745['stupxd'/215, l='ClientLevel', x=-31.66, y=90.00, z=0.97], class_745['dbstalion'/86741, l='ClientLevel', x=-6.38, y=85.00, z=-28.94], class_745['§r'/199, l='ClientLevel', x=2.59, y=87.00, z=-16.41], class_745['monarchrules'/85882, l='ClientLevel', x=3.97, y=86.17, z=-26.51], class_745['epic6539'/85854, l='ClientLevel', x=19.86, y=85.91, z=-22.76], class_745['QDucktator'/85786, l='ClientLevel', x=-23.75, y=85.00, z=-37.69], class_745['v7u9tcfs'/93956, l='ClientLevel', x=-9.50, y=90.00, z=1.50], class_745['EinEchterGulli'/87573, l='ClientLevel', x=-0.88, y=87.00, z=-7.91], class_745['nylof'/87681, l='ClientLevel', x=0.50, y=90.00, z=4.50], class_745['sagla'/87709, l='ClientLevel', x=0.44, y=90.00, z=2.84], class_745['§r'/148, l='ClientLevel', x=18.53, y=87.00, z=-47.59], class_745['§r'/172, l='ClientLevel', x=-17.53, y=87.00, z=-47.53], class_745['§r'/151, l='ClientLevel', x=14.50, y=87.00, z=-49.56], class_745['§r'/154, l='ClientLevel', x=10.56, y=87.00, z=-51.53], class_745['§r'/166, l='ClientLevel', x=-9.53, y=87.00, z=-51.44], class_745['§r'/169, l='ClientLevel', x=-13.56, y=87.00, z=-49.50]]
    Chunk stats: 18225, 361
    Level dimension: minecraft:overworld
    Level spawn location: World: (0,90,0), Section: (at 0,10,0 in 0,5,0; chunk contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 1177223165 game time, 47424000 day time
    Server brand: PaperSpigot (Velocity)
    Server type: Non-integrated multiplayer server
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.class_638.method_8538(class_638.java:455)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1587(class_310.java:2406)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.method_1514(class_310.java:820)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:237)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:468)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)

-- Last reload --
Details:
    Reload number: 1
    Reload reason: initial
    Finished: Yes
    Packs: vanilla, fabric

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.19.4
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.19.4
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 17.0.3, Microsoft
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Microsoft
    Memory: 551676232 bytes (526 MiB) / 1056964608 bytes (1008 MiB) up to 3959422976 bytes (3776 MiB)
    CPUs: 12
    Processor Vendor: AuthenticAMD
    Processor Name: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics         
    Identifier: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 96 Stepping 1
    Microarchitecture: unknown
    Frequency (GHz): 2.99
    Number of physical packages: 1
    Number of physical CPUs: 6
    Number of logical CPUs: 12
    Graphics card #0 name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
    Graphics card #0 vendor: NVIDIA (0x10de)
    Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 4095.00
    Graphics card #0 deviceId: 0x1f99
    Graphics card #0 versionInfo: DriverVersion=31.0.15.3118
    Graphics card #1 name: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics
    Graphics card #1 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. (0x1002)
    Graphics card #1 VRAM (MB): 512.00
    Graphics card #1 deviceId: 0x1636
    Graphics card #1 versionInfo: DriverVersion=27.20.15002.11002
    Memory slot #0 capacity (MB): 4096.00
    Memory slot #0 clockSpeed (GHz): 3.20
    Memory slot #0 type: DDR4
    Memory slot #1 capacity (MB): 4096.00
    Memory slot #1 clockSpeed (GHz): 3.20
    Memory slot #1 type: DDR4
    Virtual memory max (MB): 22389.06
    Virtual memory used (MB): 15744.68
    Swap memory total (MB): 14848.00
    Swap memory used (MB): 2071.96
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX: UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX: UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -Xmx3770m -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
    Fabric Mods: 
        addon-template: Dorts 0.1.0
        fabric-api: Fabric API 0.83.0 1.19.4
            fabric-api-base: Fabric API Base 0.4.27 1e9487d2f4
            fabric-api-lookup-api-v1: Fabric API Lookup API (v1) 1.6.28 504944c8f4
            fabric-biome-api-v1: Fabric Biome API (v1) 13.0.9 10ce000ff4
            fabric-block-api-v1: Fabric Block API (v1) 1.0.8 e022e5d1f4
            fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1: Fabric BlockRenderLayer Registration (v1) 1.1.37 10ce000ff4
            fabric-client-tags-api-v1: Fabric Client Tags 1.0.18 10ce000ff4
            fabric-command-api-v1: Fabric Command API (v1) 1.2.30 f71b366ff4
            fabric-command-api-v2: Fabric Command API (v2) 2.2.9 10ce000ff4
            fabric-commands-v0: Fabric Commands (v0) 0.2.47 df3654b3f4
            fabric-containers-v0: Fabric Containers (v0) 0.1.57 df3654b3f4
            fabric-content-registries-v0: Fabric Content Registries (v0) 3.5.12 10ce000ff4
            fabric-convention-tags-v1: Fabric Convention Tags 1.5.2 10ce000ff4
            fabric-crash-report-info-v1: Fabric Crash Report Info (v1) 0.2.17 aeb40ebef4
            fabric-data-generation-api-v1: Fabric Data Generation API (v1) 11.4.3 10ce000ff4
            fabric-dimensions-v1: Fabric Dimensions API (v1) 2.1.48 10ce000ff4
            fabric-entity-events-v1: Fabric Entity Events (v1) 1.5.16 10ce000ff4
            fabric-events-interaction-v0: Fabric Events Interaction (v0) 0.6.0 10ce000ff4
            fabric-events-lifecycle-v0: Fabric Events Lifecycle (v0) 0.2.55 df3654b3f4
            fabric-game-rule-api-v1: Fabric Game Rule API (v1) 1.0.35 a1ccd7bff4
            fabric-item-api-v1: Fabric Item API (v1) 2.1.20 10ce000ff4
            fabric-item-group-api-v1: Fabric Item Group API (v1) 3.0.8 10ce000ff4
            fabric-key-binding-api-v1: Fabric Key Binding API (v1) 1.0.35 504944c8f4
            fabric-keybindings-v0: Fabric Key Bindings (v0) 0.2.33 df3654b3f4
            fabric-lifecycle-events-v1: Fabric Lifecycle Events (v1) 2.2.18 10ce000ff4
            fabric-loot-api-v2: Fabric Loot API (v2) 1.1.30 10ce000ff4
            fabric-loot-tables-v1: Fabric Loot Tables (v1) 1.1.34 9e7660c6f4
            fabric-message-api-v1: Fabric Message API (v1) 5.1.4 10ce000ff4
            fabric-mining-level-api-v1: Fabric Mining Level API (v1) 2.1.42 10ce000ff4
            fabric-models-v0: Fabric Models (v0) 0.3.33 10ce000ff4
            fabric-networking-api-v1: Fabric Networking API (v1) 1.3.4 10ce000ff4
            fabric-networking-v0: Fabric Networking (v0) 0.3.44 df3654b3f4
            fabric-object-builder-api-v1: Fabric Object Builder API (v1) 7.0.6 10ce000ff4
            fabric-particles-v1: Fabric Particles (v1) 1.0.26 10ce000ff4
            fabric-recipe-api-v1: Fabric Recipe API (v1) 1.0.11 10ce000ff4
            fabric-registry-sync-v0: Fabric Registry Sync (v0) 2.2.3 10ce000ff4
            fabric-renderer-api-v1: Fabric Renderer API (v1) 2.3.1 10ce000ff4
            fabric-renderer-indigo: Fabric Renderer - Indigo 1.3.1 10ce000ff4
            fabric-renderer-registries-v1: Fabric Renderer Registries (v1) 3.2.41 df3654b3f4
            fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1: Fabric Rendering Data Attachment (v1) 0.3.31 10ce000ff4
            fabric-rendering-fluids-v1: Fabric Rendering Fluids (v1) 3.0.24 10ce000ff4
            fabric-rendering-v0: Fabric Rendering (v0) 1.1.44 df3654b3f4
            fabric-rendering-v1: Fabric Rendering (v1) 2.1.4 10ce000ff4
            fabric-resource-conditions-api-v1: Fabric Resource Conditions API (v1) 2.3.3 10ce000ff4
            fabric-resource-loader-v0: Fabric Resource Loader (v0) 0.11.5 5ade3c38f4
            fabric-screen-api-v1: Fabric Screen API (v1) 1.0.48 10ce000ff4
            fabric-screen-handler-api-v1: Fabric Screen Handler API (v1) 1.3.23 10ce000ff4
            fabric-sound-api-v1: Fabric Sound API (v1) 1.0.11 10ce000ff4
            fabric-transfer-api-v1: Fabric Transfer API (v1) 3.2.1 10ce000ff4
            fabric-transitive-access-wideners-v1: Fabric Transitive Access Wideners (v1) 3.2.0 10ce000ff4
        fabricloader: Fabric Loader 0.14.21
        java: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17
        meteor-client: Meteor Client 0.5.3
            baritone-meteor: Baritone 1.19.4-SNAPSHOT
        meteor-rejects: Meteor Rejects 0.2
            seedcrackerx-api: SeedCrackerX API 2.10.1
        minecraft: Minecraft 1.19.4
        seedcrackerx: SeedCrackerX 2.14.2
            cloth-config: Cloth Config v10 10.0.96
                cloth-basic-math: cloth-basic-math 0.6.1
            com_seedfinding_latticg: latticg 1.6
            com_seedfinding_mc_biome: mc_biome b2271807a047bb43ac60c8c20ad47e315f19b9a6
            com_seedfinding_mc_core: mc_core d685a37f0a466d4bf800e7f285daf9ef73c81678
            com_seedfinding_mc_feature: mc_feature c29fd1fcd746e14c1bcdb127da3113ba273db1fd
            com_seedfinding_mc_math: mc_math 0eb505174da8a92550f8ec6efe254e0fa936cc0d
            com_seedfinding_mc_noise: mc_noise a6ab8e6c688491829f8d2adf845392da22ef8e9c
            com_seedfinding_mc_reversal: mc_reversal ca64c0890c106f1a2207623c316fce86f250b918
            com_seedfinding_mc_seed: mc_seed 5518e3ba3ee567fb0b51c15958967f70a6a19e02
            com_seedfinding_mc_terrain: mc_terrain 9e937ddb838e28e79423c287fa18b1ce66f061d7
        uiutils: UI Utils 1.2.2
    Launched Version: fabric-loader-0.14.21-1.19.4
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.3.1 SNAPSHOT
    Backend API: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics GL version 3.2.148201 Core Profile Forward-Compatible Context **.**.**.** 27.20.15002.11002, ATI Technologies Inc.
    Window size: 1920x1080
    GL Caps: Using framebuffer using OpenGL 3.2
    GL debug messages: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fabric'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Graphics mode: fancy
    Resource Packs: vanilla, fabric
    Current Language: en_gb
    CPU: 12x AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics 
`
```

Comment: did you bother to read the stacktrace you link to? java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/client/MinecraftClient

Comment: @Stultuske so how do i even fix that

Comment: by putting that class on the classpath

Comment: @Stultuske it is on the classpath i just decompiled Minecraft client and at the top it says package net.minecraft.client;

Comment: @Stultuske and the function for getting the instance does exist because i found this in the decompiled code: `public static net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient getInstance()`

Comment: if it was on the classpath, you wouldn't get that error. Maybe there 's a problem in conflicting versions, or it's in a different scope, but you don't provide nearly sufficient information to deduct that from

Comment: @Stultuske please tell me what i need to provide i really want to fix this

Comment: I have no idea, as I said: you don't provide nearly sufficient information. let's start with: What is the structure of your project? are you using a DMS (Dependency Management System)?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're developing a server mod.
I assume the entry point to your mod is either `ServerModInitializer` (or less likely `ModInitializer`) and not `ClientModInitializer`.

If you run the mod on the server, the classes `MinecraftClient` as well as `ClientWorld` do not exist hence runtime error. In order to get the list of the players, you need to use server equivalents of these classes. The equivalent to your code would look like that:

```java
private void listPlayers(MinecraftServer minecraftServer) {
    // Get the world
    ServerWorld serverWorld = minecraftServer.getWorld(World.OVERWORLD);

    // Check if the world is available
    if (serverWorld != null) {
        // Get the list of players
        List<ServerPlayerEntity> players = serverWorld.getPlayers();

        // Iterate over the players and do something with their names
        for (ServerPlayerEntity player : players) {
            String playerName = player.getEntityName();
            // Do something with the player name
            System.out.println(playerName);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass an instance of `MinecraftServer` class to that method. I assume you're already getting it somewhere. In case you don't, you can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71059107/7438147